# Локализация приложения для украинского языка перестает работать в Google Play

Tags: java, android, locale

Использую в android приложении разные локализации, выбор которых находится в настройках в ListPreference. Изменение происходит через SharedPreferences.
Код MainActivity.java:

```
public static String storeLang; 
...   
SharedPreferences shp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);    
storeLang = shp.getString(getString(R.string.key_lang), "");

Locale locale = new Locale(storeLang);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Переменные для языков храню в arrays.xml:

```
<string-array name="lang_value">
    <item name="english">en</item>
    <item name="russian">ru</item>
    <item name="ukrainian">uk</item>
</string-array>
```

В debug и подписанном release apk приложение работало корректно, украинский язык подгружался. В Google Play был загружен app bundle, язык по-умолчанию - английский. После установки из Google Play при выборе в настройках приложения украинского языка, контент показывается на английском языке. Правильное отображение на украинском возможно только если изначально это язык телефона.
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с проблемой.

Comment: Это из-за bundle. Там по умолчанию на телефон загружается только один язык.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в build.gradle проекта:

```
android {

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!